# How can I fix that syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting T_FUNCTION?

Tags: php, wordpress

I use wordpress theme and I added some codes in functions.php . Here there: https://gist.github.com/tomhemsley/4d19646f57a0a1f20709

Then, I saw that:

Answer (score 0):

Change this line

```
if ( $datas['tried'] <= $this->failed_login_limit )
```

to this

```
if ( $datas['tried'] <= $this->failed_login_limit ) {
```

You missed the opening brace for the `if` condition. Better you use good IDE so that these type of syntax errors will be resolved.

Comment: I changed but not solved. Any idea?